# CSS animation starting from beginning

Tags: html, css

Got this problem. The "Start button" plays the animation and the sounds in the background. Whenever I pause it, I can't make the animation stop where it remained at that point. It just starts from the beginning.

Went a bit deep and tried with `animation-play-state: pause` and `animation-fill-mode: forwards` but I surely don't do something right, because I can't figure it out.

```js
function ani(){
   var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
   audio.play();
   document.getElementById('target').className ='animated';
}

function ani2(){
   var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
   audio.pause();
   document.getElementById('target').className ='noo';
}
```

```css
button {
    background-color: darkgreen; /* Green */
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 13px 50px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4), 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }

button:hover{
    background-color: green; /* Green */
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 13px 50px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer; 
    box-shadow: 0 6px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25),
        0 0 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    transform: translateY(-2px);
  }
p {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 80;
  color: black;
  overflow: hidden;

  /* Same as before */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, darkgreen, darkgreen 50%, black 50%);

  /* Same as before */
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 100%;

  /* Same as before */

}
.animated {
    transition: background-position 9000ms linear;
    background-position: 0 100%;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.noo > {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<button type = "button" id= "ST" onclick= "ani()" >Start the story!</button><br><br><br><br>

<p href="#a" id="target">Das Problem ist recht einfach, aber ich bin ein bisschen unerfahren in CSS, um es zu beheben. In dem Code, den ich unten anheften </p> 

<audio id="audio" src="https://k15xf2.webwave.dev/lib/k15xf2/Prob1-kgs9f12v.mp3"></audio>

<button type = "button" id= "ST1" onclick= "ani2()" >Pause the story!</button><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: One Question about the file. do you have a tool to convert the text to mp3 or do you have a program library?

Comment: @MaikLowrey online program ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing transition with animation. the `animation-play-state` is for animation, not for transition.

So, when you add the class `animated` that sets the `background-position`, the transition starts. When you pause, you are removing the class `animated` from the element and adding just the class `noo`, that doesn't have a backgroun-position attribute, so, the element assumes the one that is set in `p` (reseting the position to start).

To fix this, I suggest the usage of a real animation, by creating a @keyframes that goes from starting background-position to desired background-position (0 100%).

Also, don't remove the `animated` class from the element, that way, you keep the class that contains the animation, but just add the `noo` class, that is responsible to stop the animation.

See below code

```js
function ani() {
  var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  audio.play();
  document.getElementById('target').className = 'animated';
}

function ani2() {
  var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  audio.pause();
  document.getElementById('target').className = 'animated noo';
}
```

```css
button {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  /* Green */
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

button:hover {
  background-color: green;
  /* Green */
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 0 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

p {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 80;
  color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Same as before */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, darkgreen, darkgreen 50%, black 50%);
  /* Same as before */
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 100%;
}

.animated {
  animation-duration: 9s;
  animation-name: fill;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-play-state: running;
}

.noo {
  animation-play-state: paused !important;
}

@keyframes fill{
  from {
    background-position: 100%;
  }

  to {
    background-position: 0 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="ST" onclick="ani()">Start the story!</button><br><br><br><br>

<p href="#a" id="target">Das Problem ist recht einfach, aber ich bin ein bisschen unerfahren in CSS, um es zu beheben. In dem Code, den ich unten anheften </p>

<audio id="audio" src="https://k15xf2.webwave.dev/lib/k15xf2/Prob1-kgs9f12v.mp3"></audio>

<button type="button" id="ST1" onclick="ani2()">Pause the story!</button><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: thanks. i didn't think about it this way. thank u ^^